# JavaFx Platform.runLater submitted Task not getting Invoked?

Tags: multithreading, swing, javafx-8, jfxpanel

We have developed  Swing-JavaFx Integrated application for multimedia content like Image & Animations. Base Container for application is Swing JFrame. Inside, for Image we are using JFXPanel. But after continuous run of say ~12hrs and log analysis, we have observed that Task submitted to Platform.runlater is never getting executed.

PS: Platform.setImplicitExit(false) is done.
Duration of occurence is not fixed, but usually after 6hrs.
Implementation is changing images repeatedly after a defined duration.

Comment: That sounds very strange and deserves a bug report at Oracle. You can try and run swing and javafx on the same thread with the jvm option `-Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true` but be aware that this is an experimental feature. Otherwise I would suggest moving away from swing and implementing the whole application in JavaFX.

Comment: Note that for a bug report you will need to provide a [MCVE]. It would be helpful here too if you can provide one.